# CAPTCHA in Fat Free framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

How to use the CAPTCHA plugin in a login form in Fat Free framework? I have never used CAPTCHA before so I am looking for some kind of a tutorial to learn that for FatFree framework.

Can anyone point to some resource or tell me how to do this ? Specifically, I am looking to insert a CAPTCHA in a form in a template and then check for correctness when the form in submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fat Free framework already has Captcha in built

```
<img src="/captcha" title="captcha image" alt="captcha"/>
<label for="code">Security Code</label>
<input type="text" name="code"/>
<p>{@message}</p>
```

Then in your application, you should have a route to handle the /captcha URL specified inside the src attribute:

```
F3::route('GET /captcha','securityCode');
function securityCode() {
    Graphics::captcha(150,60,5);
}
```

The input validation script would be something like:-

```
F3::input('code',
    function($value) {
        if (empty($value))
            F3::set('message','Security code is required');
        elseif ($value!=$_SESSION['captcha'])
            F3::set('message','Invalid security code');
    }
);
```

See http://bcosca.github.com/fatfree/ for full documentation

There is a know error with Fat Free Captch expect you are using latest version to fix it

```
You know about the bug with captcha ()?
It's easy to fix!
Line number 81 in graphics.php with the error:
$ file = self:: $ global ['FONTS'].

Corrected version:
$ file = __DIR__ .'/../ fonts / '. self:: $ global [' FONTS '].
```

See : http://techzinger.blogspot.com/2011/02/fat-free-framework-for.html?showComment=1298024374012#c4330544534362949394

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am getting some error like filesize() [<a href='function.filesize'>function.filesize</a>]: stat failed for /var/www/cube.ttf.

In graphics.php, there is no such line that you have told to fix. The line is $file=&self::vars['FONTS']. What should I do?

Comment: I actually got it. I had to set F3::set('FONTS', /path/to/fonts/folder') as it was different.

Comment: I use Google Recaptcha which is superb working with F3 :p